# How to use static in express js on OS X?

Tags: node.js, express, osx-mavericks

Faced with strange problem: can't setup static folder for `express js`.

- Folder that should be static: `/Users/user/Sites/move/assets`
- Server.js file: `/Users/user/Sites/move/app/server.js`
- URL i use: `http://localhost:5001/assets/css/bootstrap.css`

`Server.js` file looks like this:

```
function Run(config) {
    var express = require('express'),
        ejs = require('ejs');

    var app = express();

    app.configure(function() {
        // express.static(config.APP_BASE_PATH + '/assets' prints /Users/user/Sites/move/assets
        app.use(express.static(config.APP_BASE_PATH + '/assets'));
        // Also used
        // app.use('assets', express.static(config.APP_BASE_PATH + '/assets'));
    });

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index.html');
    });

    app.listen(config.APP_PORT);
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to create application skeleton with configured static assets, using npm and expres command.

```
npm install -g express

express --sessions --css stylus --ejs myapp
```

Comment: and what the difference between your static and mine?

Comment: how can I compare it, I don't know what config object is.

Comment: `// express.static(config.APP_BASE_PATH + '/assets' prints /Users/user/Sites/move/assets
`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it. Do you try it create skeleton application form command line?

Answer (score 0):

When you say this:

```
app.use(express.static(config.APP_BASE_PATH + '/assets'));
```

It means that a request for `/assets/css/bootstrap.css` will be looked up as:

```
config.APP_BASE_PATH + '/assets' + '/assets/css/bootstrap.css'
```

Which is clearly not what you want.

Instead, you can prefix the middleware declaration:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(config.APP_BASE_PATH + '/assets'));
```

Which means that if a request starts with `/assets`, the static middleware will take everything after that prefix (so `/css/bootstrap.css`) and look *that* up in the directory that you passed.

The starting `/` is important, otherwise it won't match the incoming request.